# Complexity of reverse sentence algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I was working on a data-structure problem in Python where I have to reverse the order of the words in the array in the most efficient manner. I came up with the following solution to the problem

```
def reverse(arr, st, end):
    while st < end:
        arr[st], arr[end] = arr[end], arr[st]
        end -= 1
        st += 1

def reverse_arr(arr):
    arr = arr[::-1]
    st_index = 0
    length = len(arr)

    for i, val in enumerate(arr):
        if val == ' ':
            end_index = i-1
            reverse(arr, st_index, end_index)
            st_index = end_index + 2

        if i == length - 1:
            reverse(arr, st_index, length-1)

    return arr
```

If the arr is:

```
arr = [ 'p', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'e', 'c', 't', ' ',
        'm', 'a', 'k', 'e', 's', ' ',
        'p', 'r', 'a', 'c', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e' ]
```

It returns:

```
['p', 'r', 'a', 'c', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e', ' ', 
 'm', 'a', 'k', 'e', 's', ' ', 
 'p', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'e', 'c', 't']
```

The solution works fine but I don't understand how the complexity of this algorithm is O(n). It's written that traversing the array twice with a constant number of actions for each item is linear i.e. O(n) where n is the length of the array.

I think it should be more than O(n) as according to me the length of each word is not fixed and time complexity to reverse each word depends on the length of the word. Can someone explain this in a better way?

Comment: O(n) is not constant time, which is O(1), it is linear time and so the time taken does depend on the length of the `list`; I think you need to read more about time complexity

Comment: @Chris_Rands I think it should be more than linear as we should also take into account reversing each word. I did not understand how the complexity of reversing each word is O(1).

Comment: You also could look at this as `O(n * k)`, where `n` is length of array and `k` is average length of words.  In scientifiec article you'd have to include both, even do analysis of `k`, but in usual case you can assume `k` is somewhat constant. For datasets with longer words it will be bit higher, for normal texts it might fluctuate a bit, but for texts long enough it will stay constant. If your input is actual words, you will rarely see something of length 25+ (unless processing german). All in all, it can easly be considered unimportant.

Comment: the n in O(n) here is the length of the entire list `arr`, which is the cumulative length of all the words (reverseing each word individually would be O(n) too, where n is the length of the word)

Comment: Just to note that in Python - trying to manipulate things at this level is verbose and not very efficient... in fact - `[ch for word in ' '.join(''.join(arr).split()[::-1]) for ch in word]` - is almost twice as fast for instance and that's not even trying to make anything meet any O(something)... But I digress - if you're just trying to show it in Python and focusing on the design that's fine, it's O(N), but in Python - you wouldn't want to do this...

Comment: I agree with @JonClements. I would even go without the `for` with : `rev_arr = list(' '.join(''.join(arr).split()[::-1]))` (around 3 times faster)

Comment: @JonClements I appreciate you for suggesting the better way without using for loop. I had a question regarding the approach that I have used and why the length of the word is not considered in the time complexity.

Comment: @Nuageux ahh yes... not sure what I was thinking with the `for` there - completely unneeded - good catch :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reverse` will get called once for each word. During that call, it will do a constant amount of work per character.

You can either represent this in terms of the number of words and average length of words (i.e. `O(wordCount*averageWordLength)`), or in terms of the total number of characters in the array. If you do the latter, it's easy to see that you're still doing a constant amount of work per character (since both `reverse` and `reverse_arr` does a constant amount of work per character, and no two `reverse` calls will include the same character), leading to `O(characterCount)` complexity.

I would not assume that "the length of the array" in the explanation refers to the number of words, but rather the number of characters, or they're assuming the word length has a fixed upper bound (in which the complexity is indeed `O(wordCount)`).

**TL;DR:** `n` in `O(n)` is `characterCount`, not `wordCount`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def reverse(arr, st, end):
    while st < end:
        arr[st], arr[end] = arr[end], arr[st]
        end -= 1
        st += 1

def reverse_Cha(arr):
    arr = arr[::-1]
    st_index = 0
    length = len(arr)

    for i, val in enumerate(arr):
        if val == ' ':
            end_index = i-1
            reverse(arr, st_index, end_index)
            st_index = end_index + 2

        if i == length - 1:
            reverse(arr, st_index, length-1)

    return arr

def reverse_Jon(arr):
    r = [ch for word in ' '.join(''.join(arr).split()[::-1]) for ch in word]
    return r

def reverse_Nua(arr):
    rev_arr = list(' '.join(''.join(arr).split()[::-1]))
    return rev_arr
```

If we considered the 3 proposed solutions: yours as `reverse_Cha`, Jon Clements' as `reverse_Jon`, and mine as `reverse_Nua`.
We note that we have `O(n)` when we use `[::-1]`, when we examine each elements of a list (length `n`), etc.

`reverse_Cha` uses `[::-1]`, then examine each elements twice (to read then to exchange), complexity is thus depending on the total number of elements (`O(3n+c)` which we write as `O(n)` (`+c` comes from `O(1)` operations))

`reverse_Jon` uses `[::-1]`, then examine each elements twice (examine each character of each word), complexity is thus depending on the total number of elements and number of words (`O(3n+m)` which we write as `O(n+m)` (with `m` the number of words))

`reverse_Nua` uses `[::-1]`, then stick to python list functions, complexity is thus still depending on the total number of elements (Just `O(n)` directly this time)

As term of performance (1e6 loops), we got `reverse_Cha`: 2.785867s; `reverse_Jon`: 4.11845s (due to `for`); `reverse_Nua`: 1.185973s.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a purely theoretical question, because in real world applications you would probably rather split your list into one-word sublists, then rejoin the sublists in reverse order - that requires more memory, but is much faster.

Having said that, I'd like to point out that the algorithm you've shown is, indeed, O(n) - it depends on **total** length of your words, not on lengths of individual words. In other words: it will take the same time for 20 3-letter words, 6 10-letter words, 10 6-letter words… you always go through every letter only twice: once during reversal of individual words (that's the first call to `reverse` in `reverse_arr`) and once during reversal of the whole array (the second call to `reverse`).

Comment: I agree that it will take the same time for 20 3-letter words, 6 10-letter words, 10 6-letter words but the length of words is not fixed. It is not mentioned anywhere that all the words are of fixed length.

Comment: Oh, that doesn't matter. As long as the sum of word lengths is the same, the execution time remains the same, for example "10 3-letter  words and 5 6-letter words" is also the same time as all other examples above.